# WCF Client not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

i have a MVC.NET Application and for login to application i need to use a WFC service.

this is my configuration file

```
<system.serviceModel>    
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <clear />
        <binding name="CoreServiceHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16348" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>            
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <clear />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/CoreServiceApp/LoginService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreServiceHttpBinding"
        contract="ServiceLogin.ILoginService" name="CoreServiceHttpBinding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

the address (http://localhost/CoreServiceApp/LoginService.svc) is working fine in a web browser, but in apllication throw me thi exception:

```
Error Message: [EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at "url" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.]
```

I only have a release build of the service.
Anonymous access is allowed on IIS
The service runs on HTTP, HTTPS is not allowed

The project uses a shared assembly with a web service that contains basic view-models for displaying data and has a re-used type from this assembly

Do you have any idea why the service is not working?

Thank you for the advice

Comment: Maybe you should show how you make the call. Did you generate a service reference?

Comment: The problem is already resolved. I do not know where the bug was, but restart IIS over the console and fix it all